# postfix tls configuration with several IPs

Tags: postfix, gmail

I'm trying to configure postfix to encrypt outgoing mails with different keys for several IPs.

main.cf `postconf -n`:

```
    alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
    alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
    anvil_rate_time_unit = 86400s
    anvil_status_update_time = 120s
    append_dot_mydomain = no
    biff = no
    compatibility_level = 2
    inet_interfaces = all
    inet_protocols = ipv4
    mailbox_size_limit = 0
    milter_default_action = accept
    milter_protocol = 6
    mydestination = $myhostname, domain.com, localhost.localdomain, localhost.localdomain, localhost
    myhostname = domain.com
    mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
    myorigin = /etc/mailname
    non_smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891
    readme_directory = no
    recipient_delimiter = +
    relayhost =
    sender_dependent_default_transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sender_transport
    smtp_tls_mandatory_ciphers = high
    smtp_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2,!SSLv3
    smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
    smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
    smtpd_client_event_limit_exceptions = $mynetworks
    smtpd_client_message_rate_limit = 200
    smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
    smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891
    smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
    smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
    smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname
    smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
    smtpd_tls_mandatory_ciphers = high
    smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2,!SSLv3
    smtpd_tls_security_level = may
    smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
    smtpd_use_tls = yes
    tls_high_cipherlist = ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!3DES:!MD5:!PSK
```

master.cf:

```
    smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
    #smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       1       postscreen
    #smtpd     pass  -       -       y       -       -       smtpd
    #dnsblog   unix  -       -       y       -       0       dnsblog
    #tlsproxy  unix  -       -       y       -       0       tlsproxy
    #submission inet n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
    127.0.0.1:submission inet n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
      -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
      -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
      -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
      -o smtpd_sasl_security_options=noanonymous
      -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
      -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
      -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
      -o smtpd_tls_cert_file=/srv/letsencrypt/ssl/domain.com/domain.com_chained.crt
      -o smtpd_tls_key_file=/srv/letsencrypt/ssl/domain.com/domain.com.key

    # domain2.com
    111.1.1.222:submission inet n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
      -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
      -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
      -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
      -o smtpd_sasl_security_options=noanonymous
      -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
      -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
      -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
      -o smtpd_tls_key_file=/srv/letsencrypt/ssl/domain2.com/domain2.com.key
      -o smtpd_tls_cert_file=/srv/letsencrypt/ssl/domain2.com/domain2.com_chained.crt
```

mail.log:

```
    Oct 28 11:43:05 zipserver postfix/postfix-script[2239]: starting the Postfix mail system
    Oct 28 11:43:05 zipserver postfix/master[2241]: daemon started -- version 3.3.0, configuration /etc/postfix
    Oct 28 11:43:32 zipserver postfix/pickup[2242]: 0BFA8104115B: uid=1000 from=<test@domain.com>
    Oct 28 11:43:32 zipserver postfix/cleanup[2248]: 0BFA8104115B: message-id=<20201028104332.0BFA8104115B@domain.com>
    Oct 28 11:43:32 zipserver postfix/qmgr[2243]: 0BFA8104115B: from=<test@domain.com>, size=407, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
    Oct 28 11:43:32 zipserver postfix/smtp[2250]: 0BFA8104115B: to=<myaccount@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[64.233.167.27]:25, delay=0.46, delays=0.13/0.01/0.05/0.27, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK  1603881812 s81si4271295wmf.188 - gsmtp)
    Oct 28 11:43:32 zipserver postfix/qmgr[2243]: 0BFA8104115B: removed
```

version:

```
    postconf -d | grep mail_version
    mail_version = 3.3.0
```

But email arrives to gmail with red crossed lock and gmail says that it was not encrypted.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Start by setting `smtp_tls_security_level=may` or higher.**

You have not set any option that would allow postfix to deviate from its defaults of not using TLS for outgoing mail. There are other and more fine-grained methods of controlling this behaviour available - but this is the most basic setting allowing to use what is offered. Use `man 5 postconf` to read about the specific meaning of the other possible options.

To help further investigations, I recommend also setting `smtp_tls_log_level=1` (to have this information in your syslog) and `smtpd_tls_received_header=yes` (to publish information about your mail submission inside the mail headers).